# React useReducer async data fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'am trying to fetch some data with new react useReducer API and stuck on stage where i need to fetch it async. I just don't know how :/

How to place data fetching in switch statement or it's not a way how it's should be done?

```
import React from 'react'

const ProfileContext = React.createContext()

const initialState = {
  data: false
}

let reducer = async (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'unload':
      return initialState
    case 'reload':
      return { data: reloadProfile() } //how to do it???
  }
}


const reloadProfile = async () => {
  try {
    let profileData = await fetch('/profile')
    profileData = await profileData.json()

    return profileData
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

function ProfileContextProvider(props) {
  let [profile, profileR] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  return (
    <ProfileContext.Provider value={{ profile, profileR }}>
      {props.children}
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { ProfileContext, ProfileContextProvider }
```

I was trying to do it like this, but it's not working with async ;(

```
let reducer = async (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'unload':
      return initialState
    case 'reload': {
      return await { data: 2 }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you want your reducer to be synchronous. Maybe you could set a value like e.g. `loading` to `true` in the `reload` case, and in your component have an effect that re-runs when `loading` changes, e.g. `useEffect(() => { if (loading) { reloadProfile().then(...) } }, [loading]);`

Comment: Perhaps useful for anyone coming across this question: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is a good practice to [keep reducers pure](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#rules-of-reducers). It will make `useReducer` more predictable and ease up testability. Subsequent approaches both combine async operations with pure reducers:

### 1. Fetch data before `dispatch` (simple)

Wrap the original `dispatch` with `asyncDispatch` and let context pass this function down:

```
const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState);
  const asyncDispatch = () => { // adjust args to your needs
    dispatch({ type: "loading" });
    fetchData().then(data => {
      dispatch({ type: "finished", payload: data });
    });
  };
  
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch: asyncDispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
  // Note: memoize the context value, if Provider gets re-rendered more often
};
```

```js
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === "loading") return { status: "loading" };
  if (type === "finished") return { status: "finished", data: payload };
  return state;
};

const initState = {
  status: "idle"
};

const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initState);
  const asyncDispatch = () => { // adjust args to your needs
    dispatch({ type: "loading" });
    fetchData().then(data => {
      dispatch({ type: "finished", payload: data });
    });
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch: asyncDispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <AppContextProvider>
      <Child />
    </AppContextProvider>
  );
}

const Child = () => {
  const val = React.useContext(AppContext);
  const {
    state: { status, data },
    dispatch
  } = val;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Status: {status}</p>
      <p>Data: {data || "-"}</p>
      <button onClick={dispatch}>Fetch data</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function fetchData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(42);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

### 2. Use middleware for `dispatch` (generic)

`dispatch` might be enhanced with [middlewares](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable), [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) for more flexibility and reusability. Or [write your own](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#writing-custom-middleware) one.

Let's say, we want to 1.) fetch async data with `redux-thunk` 2.) do some logging 3.) invoke `dispatch` with the final result. First define middlewares:

```
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
const middlewares = [thunk, logger]; // logger is our own implementation
```

Then write a custom `useMiddlewareReducer` Hook, which you can see here as `useReducer` bundled with additional middlewares, akin to Redux [`applyMiddleware`](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware#arguments):

```
const [state, dispatch] = useMiddlewareReducer(middlewares, reducer, initState);
```

Middlewares are passed as first argument, otherwise API is the same as `useReducer`. For the implementation, we take `applyMiddleware` [source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/9e71b4c/src/applyMiddleware.ts#L62-L81) and carry it over to React Hooks.

```js
const middlewares = [ReduxThunk, logger];

const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === "loading") return { ...state, status: "loading" };
  if (type === "finished") return { status: "finished", data: payload };
  return state;
};

const initState = {
  status: "idle"
};

const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useMiddlewareReducer(
    middlewares,
    reducer,
    initState
  );
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <AppContextProvider>
      <Child />
    </AppContextProvider>
  );
}

const Child = () => {
  const val = React.useContext(AppContext);
  const {
    state: { status, data },
    dispatch
  } = val;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Status: {status}</p>
      <p>Data: {data || "-"}</p>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(fetchData())}>Fetch data</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function fetchData() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: "loading" });
    setTimeout(() => {
      // fake async loading
      dispatch({ type: "finished", payload: (getState().data || 0) + 42 });
    }, 2000);
  };
}

function logger({ getState }) {
  return next => action => {
    console.log("state:", JSON.stringify(getState()), "action:", JSON.stringify(action));
    return next(action);
  };
}

// same API as useReducer, with middlewares as first argument
function useMiddlewareReducer(
  middlewares,
  reducer,
  initState,
  initializer = s => s
) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initializer(initState));
  const stateRef = React.useRef(state); // stores most recent state
  const dispatch = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      enhanceDispatch({
        getState: () => stateRef.current, // access most recent state
        stateDispatch: action => {
          stateRef.current = reducer(stateRef.current, action); // makes getState() possible
          setState(stateRef.current); // trigger re-render
          return action;
        }
      })(...middlewares),
    [middlewares, reducer]
  );

  return [state, dispatch];
}

//                                                         |  dispatch fn  |
// A middleware has type (dispatch, getState) => nextMw => action => action
function enhanceDispatch({ getState, stateDispatch }) {
  return (...middlewares) => {
    let dispatch;
    const middlewareAPI = {
      getState,
      dispatch: action => dispatch(action)
    };
    dispatch = middlewares
      .map(m => m(middlewareAPI))
      .reduceRight((next, mw) => mw(next), stateDispatch);
    return dispatch;
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux-thunk/2.3.0/redux-thunk.min.js" integrity="sha256-2xw5MpPcdu82/nmW2XQ6Ise9hKxziLWV2GupkS9knuw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>var ReduxThunk = window.ReduxThunk.default</script>
```

Note: we store intermediate state in [mutable refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) - `stateRef.current = reducer(...)`, so each middleware can access current, most recent state at the time of its invocation with [`getState`](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate).

To have the *exact* API as `useReducer`, you can create the Hook dynamically:

```
const useMiddlewareReducer = createUseMiddlewareReducer(middlewares); //init Hook
const MyComp = () => { // later on in several components
  // ...
  const [state, dispatch] = useMiddlewareReducer(reducer, initState);
}
```

```js
const middlewares = [ReduxThunk, logger];

const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === "loading") return { ...state, status: "loading" };
  if (type === "finished") return { status: "finished", data: payload };
  return state;
};

const initState = {
  status: "idle"
};

const AppContext = React.createContext();

const useMiddlewareReducer = createUseMiddlewareReducer(middlewares);

const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useMiddlewareReducer(
    reducer,
    initState
  );
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <AppContextProvider>
      <Child />
    </AppContextProvider>
  );
}

const Child = () => {
  const val = React.useContext(AppContext);
  const {
    state: { status, data },
    dispatch
  } = val;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Status: {status}</p>
      <p>Data: {data || "-"}</p>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(fetchData())}>Fetch data</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function fetchData() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: "loading" });
    setTimeout(() => {
      // fake async loading
      dispatch({ type: "finished", payload: (getState().data || 0) + 42 });
    }, 2000);
  };
}

function logger({ getState }) {
  return next => action => {
    console.log("state:", JSON.stringify(getState()), "action:", JSON.stringify(action));
    return next(action);
  };
}

function createUseMiddlewareReducer(middlewares) {
  return (reducer, initState, initializer = s => s) => {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState(initializer(initState));
    const stateRef = React.useRef(state); // stores most recent state
    const dispatch = React.useMemo(
      () =>
        enhanceDispatch({
          getState: () => stateRef.current, // access most recent state
          stateDispatch: action => {
            stateRef.current = reducer(stateRef.current, action); // makes getState() possible
            setState(stateRef.current); // trigger re-render
            return action;
          }
        })(...middlewares),
      [middlewares, reducer]
    );
    return [state, dispatch];
  }
}

//                                                         |  dispatch fn  |
// A middleware has type (dispatch, getState) => nextMw => action => action
function enhanceDispatch({ getState, stateDispatch }) {
  return (...middlewares) => {
    let dispatch;
    const middlewareAPI = {
      getState,
      dispatch: action => dispatch(action)
    };
    dispatch = middlewares
      .map(m => m(middlewareAPI))
      .reduceRight((next, mw) => mw(next), stateDispatch);
    return dispatch;
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux-thunk/2.3.0/redux-thunk.min.js" integrity="sha256-2xw5MpPcdu82/nmW2XQ6Ise9hKxziLWV2GupkS9knuw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>var ReduxThunk = window.ReduxThunk.default</script>
```

**More infos - external libraries:** [`react-use`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/createReducer.md), [`react-hooks-global-state`](https://github.com/dai-shi/react-hooks-global-state), [`react-enhanced-reducer-hook`](https://github.com/shiningjason/react-enhanced-reducer-hook)

Comment: In the first method, as `dispatch` is asynchronous, it is possible that it completes the action much later. How to ensure that the dispatch is completed before we start fetching the data?

Comment: @AdityaVerma You can't without adding much more complexity here. But why decrease perceived responsiveness for the user? By React design the async processing phase is transparent to the developer. The `dispatch` are executed in order, so you always get `loading` before `finished` - and the dispatch and pure reducer itself should be very fast, as the . In the worst case you don't see `loading`.

Comment: Solution 1 is does not make sense if your fetch operations includes the updated state. The state given to the operation will have the original state - because the update process is being executed async.

Comment: Looking into this approach I was hoping to use approach one since it is the simplest. The issue I have is that the asyncDispatch is used for entire state. What if you only want to update one part of the state and need to do an async fetch but the other state needs to remain.

Answer (score 101):

This is an interesting case that the `useReducer` examples don't touch on. I don't think the reducer is the right place to load asynchronously. Coming from a Redux mindset, you would typically load the data elsewhere, either in a thunk, an observable (ex. redux-observable), or just in a lifecycle event like `componentDidMount`. With the new `useReducer` we could use the `componentDidMount` approach using `useEffect`. Your effect can be something like the following:

```
function ProfileContextProvider(props) {
  let [profile, profileR] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    reloadProfile().then((profileData) => {
      profileR({
        type: "profileReady",
        payload: profileData
      });
    });
  }, []); // The empty array causes this effect to only run on mount

  return (
    <ProfileContext.Provider value={{ profile, profileR }}>
      {props.children}
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Also, working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/r4ml2x864m.

If you need to pass a prop or state through to your `reloadProfile` function, you could do so by adjusting the second argument to `useEffect` (the empty array in the example) so that it runs only when needed. You would need to either check against the previous value or implement some sort of cache to avoid fetching when unnecessary.

## Update - Reload from child

If you want to be able to reload from a child component, there are a couple of ways you can do that. The first option is passing a callback to the child component that will trigger the dispatch. This can be done through the context provider or a component prop. Since you are using context provider already, here is an example of that method:

```
function ProfileContextProvider(props) {
  let [profile, profileR] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const onReloadNeeded = useCallback(async () => {
    const profileData = await reloadProfile();
    profileR({
      type: "profileReady",
      payload: profileData
    });
  }, []); // The empty array causes this callback to only be created once per component instance

  useEffect(() => {
    onReloadNeeded();
  }, []); // The empty array causes this effect to only run on mount

  return (
    <ProfileContext.Provider value={{ onReloadNeeded, profile }}>
      {props.children}
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

If you *really* want to use the dispatch function instead of an explicit callback, you can do so by wrapping the dispatch in a higher order function that handles the special actions that would have been handled by middleware in the Redux world. Here is an example of that. Notice that instead of passing `profileR` directly into the context provider, we pass the custom one that acts like a middleware, intercepting special actions that the reducer doesn't care about.

```
function ProfileContextProvider(props) {
  let [profile, profileR] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const customDispatch= useCallback(async (action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "reload": {
        const profileData = await reloadProfile();
        profileR({
          type: "profileReady",
          payload: profileData
        });
        break;
      }
      default:
        // Not a special case, dispatch the action
        profileR(action);
    }
  }, []); // The empty array causes this callback to only be created once per component instance

  return (
    <ProfileContext.Provider value={{ profile, profileR: customDispatch }}>
      {props.children}
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: but how can i reload my profile from another component using switch of reducer? Previously i've passed a fetching function that changed value in provider on top level.

Comment: I've added some examples of giving the child components a method of reloading the data in the parent. Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes, thank you, Working when i added break; to reload case!

Comment: You want to avoid using `useEffect(async () => {})` The first function's return statement in `useEffect` is for cleanup and this would always return a promise immediately. This will warn (and maybe be no-op) when hooks are live.

Comment: Good catch Nate! I forgot about the cleanup function. I updated my answer to not return a Promise in useEffect.

Comment: here is a very nice article which also applies a same approach https://medium.com/@patrick.gross1987/how-to-use-the-react-context-api-with-an-asynchronous-reducer-5651c2dc26aa

Comment: Not the OP, but thanks for this answer! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: can't understand why in the case of _Reload from child_ why not just use **useState**, since the context provider is behaving just like a reducer?

Comment: Went through so many articles to learn about useReducer, nowhere mentioned any ex. about async calls. I tried myself for hours to find that it is not changing the state at all and is in fact not supported. Lol

Answer (score 21):

I wrote a very detailed explanation of the problem and possible solutions. Dan Abramov suggested Solution 3.

Note: The examples in the gist provide examples with file operations but the same approach could be implemented for data fetching.

https://gist.github.com/astoilkov/013c513e33fe95fa8846348038d8fe42

Answer (score 11):

**Update:**

I’ve added another comment in the weblink below. It’s a custom hook called `useAsyncReducer` based on the code below that uses the exact same signature as a normal `useReducer`.

```
function useAsyncReducer(reducer, initState) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initState),
        dispatchState = async (action) => setState(await reducer(state, action));
    return [state, dispatchState];
}

async function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'switch1':
            // Do async code here
            return 'newState';
    }
}

function App() {
    const [state, dispatchState] = useAsyncReducer(reducer, 'initState');
    return <ExampleComponent dispatchState={dispatchState} />;
}

function ExampleComponent({ dispatchState }) {
    return <button onClick={() => dispatchState({ type: 'switch1' })}>button</button>;
}
```

**Old solution:**

I just posted this reply [here](https://gist.github.com/astoilkov/013c513e33fe95fa8846348038d8fe42) and thought it may be good to post here as well in case it helps anyone.

My solution was to emulate `useReducer` using `useState` + an async function:

```
async function updateFunction(action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'switch1':
            // Do async code here (access current state with 'action.state')
            action.setState('newState');
            break;
    }
}

function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState(),
        callUpdateFunction = (vars) => updateFunction({ ...vars, state, setState });

    return <ExampleComponent callUpdateFunction={callUpdateFunction} />;
}

function ExampleComponent({ callUpdateFunction }) {
    return <button onClick={() => callUpdateFunction({ type: 'switch1' })} />
}
```

Comment: There is misunderstanding about what a reducer is. It's supposed to be a pure function without side-effects for the purpose of testing.

Comment: Attention, this solution is vulnerable to race conditions. The async reducer may capture an outdated `state` input and overwrite a faster update that happened after.

Answer (score 5):

I wrapped the dispatch method with a layer to solve the asynchronous action problem.

Here is initial state. The `loading` key record the application current loading status, It's convenient when you want to show loading page when the application is fetching data from server.

```js
{
  value: 0,
  loading: false
}
```

There are four kinds of actions.

```js
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "click_async":
    case "click_sync":
      return { ...state, value: action.payload };
    case "loading_start":
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case "loading_end":
      return { ...state, loading: false };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
```

```js
function isPromise(obj) {
  return (
    !!obj &&
    (typeof obj === "object" || typeof obj === "function") &&
    typeof obj.then === "function"
  );
}

function wrapperDispatch(dispatch) {
  return function(action) {
    if (isPromise(action.payload)) {
      dispatch({ type: "loading_start" });
      action.payload.then(v => {
        dispatch({ type: action.type, payload: v });
        dispatch({ type: "loading_end" });
      });
    } else {
      dispatch(action);
    }
  };
}
```

Suppose there is an asynchronous method

```js
async function asyncFetch(p) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(p);
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

```js
wrapperDispatch(dispatch)({
  type: "click_async",
  payload: asyncFetch(new Date().getTime())
});
```

The full example code is here:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/13qnv8ml7q

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple
you can change state in useEffect after async Fuction result

define `useState` for result of fetch

`const [resultFetch, setResultFetch] = useState(null);`

and `useEffect` for listen to `setResultFetch`

after fetch async API call `setResultFetch(result of response)`

```
useEffect(() => {
if (resultFetch) {
  const user = resultFetch;
  dispatch({ type: AC_USER_LOGIN, userId: user.ID})

}}, [resultFetch])
```