# React.js tells you to cancel promises. Official Promises can't be cancelled. What am I supposed to do instead?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, cancellation

In order to prevent phantom updates to an unmounted React component, React tells you to [cancel any pending promises](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) on a component (such as promises for fetching additional data) when it unmounts. This is very easy to accomplish with Bluebird promises, which have a `.cancel()` method on them that causes the `.then()` and `.catch()` handlers to never respond.

However, ES6 Promises do not support cancellation. In addition, ES7's `async` and `await` only use native Promises and do not support any drop-in replacements (such as Bluebird). This means that if you want to be able to cancel Promises in React, as they tell you to do, you have to use `.then()` and `.catch()` and also have to place a middleman on native Promise methods like `fetch()` so that it can be cancelled.

Is this really what React expects?

Comment: A common pattern is to move async loading into your store (something like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)) and make code inside your React components strictly synchronous. This is not an indication that React is on its way out, it's that the React team has identified mixing async code in your views leads to more problems despite its short term convenience and speed. You can also read the 2015 post that still applies today about [isMounted is an Antipattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) for other ways to address this.

Comment: Would you please place a link to React documentation page with that advice in it?

Comment: I suggest starting with [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), which ships with React, to understand the flow of a central storage object for your application's state. There are other questions about doing [async fetches with `useReducer`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53146795/368697) that would enable your setup too.

Comment: you tried to add an setTimeout inside to throw an error or reject the promise?

Comment: if you just want awaitable "cancelable" Promises here's a jsfiddle using a Promise wrapped monkey patch: https://jsfiddle.net/x6ah7qog/1/  It's a bit inelegant, admittedly.

Comment: The link in the question (regarding isMounted) actually has a nice makeCancellable wrapper example for use around a generic es6 promise. Seems like a good workaround when you can't abstract the async processes to something more centralized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest React docs (Aug 2023), suggest 2 solutions to this issue:

1. Create a new 'ignore' variable that is set to true during the Effect cleanup. When the Promise returns, ignore the result based on the variable.
2. Use the [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) API to cancel the asynchronous action.

Check the solution to 'Challenge 4 of 4' on [this page](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects) of the React Docs.

Comment: An abort signal does not cancel the promise, it cancels the asynchronous action (e.g. the HTTP fetch)

Answer (score 0):

Just for your reference.
Using [CPromise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-promise2) package, you can cancel your promise chains, including nested ones. It supports AbortController and generators as a replacement for ECMA async functions. Currently the project in the beta stage.

Generator usage [Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-fog-01x8z?file=/src/index.js) :

```
import CPromise from "c-promise2";

const chain = CPromise.resolve()
  .then(function* () {
    const value1 = yield new CPromise((resolve, reject, { onCancel }) => {
      const timer = setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 3);
      onCancel(() => {
        console.log("timer cleared");
        clearTimeout(timer);
      });
    });
    // Run promises in parallel using CPromise.all (shortcut syntax)
    const [value2, value3] = yield [
      CPromise.delay(1000, 4),
      CPromise.delay(1000, 5)
    ];
    return value1 + value2 + value3;
  })
  .then(
    (value) => {
      console.log(`Done: ${value}`); // Done: 12 (without calling cancel)
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(`Failed: ${err}`); // Failed: CanceledError: canceled
    }
  );

setTimeout(() => chain.cancel(), 100);
```

Output:

```
timer cleared 
Failed: CanceledError: canceled
```

**All stages there are completely cancelable/abortable.**
Here is an example of using it with React [Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-classes-await-listen-forked-sgx3y?file=/src/TestComponent.js)

```
export class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mounted");
    this.controller = new CPromise.AbortController();
    try {
      const json = await this.myAsyncTask(
        "https://run.mocky.io/v3/7b038025-fc5f-4564-90eb-4373f0721822?mocky-delay=2s"
      );
      console.log("json:", json);
      await this.myAsyncTaskWithDelay(1000, 123); // just another async task
      this.setState({ text: JSON.stringify(json) });
    } catch (err) {
      if (CPromise.isCanceledError(err)) {
        console.log("tasks terminated");
      }
    }
  }

  myAsyncTask(url) {
    return CPromise.from(function* () {
      const response = yield cpFetch(url); // cancellable request
      return yield response.json();
    }).listen(this.controller.signal);
  }

  myAsyncTaskWithDelay(ms, value) {
    return new CPromise((resolve, reject, { onCancel }) => {
      const timer = setTimeout(resolve, ms, value);
      onCancel(() => {
        console.log("timeout cleared");
        clearTimeout(timer);
      });
    }).listen(this.controller.signal);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        AsyncComponent: <span>{this.state.text || "fetching..."}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("unmounted");
    this.controller.abort(); // kill all pending tasks
  }
}
```

[Using Hooks and `cancel` method](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-hooks-generators-forked-gy30b?file=/src/TestComponent.js)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import CPromise from "c-promise2";
import cpFetch from "cp-fetch";

export function TestComponent(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("fetching...");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mount");
    const promise = cpFetch(props.url)
      .then(function* (response) {
        const json = yield response.json();
        setText(`Delay for 2000ms...`);
        yield CPromise.delay(2000);
        setText(`Success: ${JSON.stringify(json)}`);
      })
      .canceled()
      .catch((err) => {
        setText(`Failed: ${err}`);
      });

    return () => {
      console.log("unmount");
      promise.cancel();
    };
  }, [props.url]);

  return <p>{text}</p>;
}
```