# Problem with custom ContextProvider state when using custom hook for fetching data in multiple tables in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have multiple tables, of small size, and I want to be able to write / read / update my components when the corresponding table has been updated by the app (we can consider it's a single user app for the moment).

I've been inspired by this question to write a custom Provider and associated hook for data fetching (and eventually posting) in my app: [React useReducer async data fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146795/react-usereducer-async-data-fetch)

I came up with this:

```
import React from "react";
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const MetadataContext = React.createContext();

function MetadataContextProvider(props) {
  let [metadata, setMetadata] = useState({});

  async function loadMetadata(url) {
    let response = await axios.get(url);
    // here when I console.log the value of metadata I get {} all the time
    setMetadata({ ...metadata, [url]: response.data });
  }

  async function postNewItem(url, payload) {
    await axios.post(url, payload);
    let response = await axios.get(url);
    setMetadata({ ...metadata, [url]: response.data });
  }

  return (
    <MetadataContext.Provider value={{ metadata, loadMetadata, postNewItem }}>
      {props.children}
    </MetadataContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useMetadataTable(url) {
  // this hook's goal is to allow loading data in the context provider
  // when required by some component
  const context = useContext(MetadataContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    context.loadMetadata(url);
  }, []);

  return [
    context.metadata[url],
    () => context.loadMetadata(url),
    (payload) => context.postNewItem(url, payload),
  ];
}

function TestComponent({ url }) {
  const [metadata, loadMetadata, postNewItem] = useMetadataTable(url);
  // not using loadMetadata and postNewItem here

  return (
    <>
      <p> {JSON.stringify(metadata)} </p>
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <MetadataContextProvider>
      <TestComponent url="/api/capteur" />
      <br />
      <TestComponent url="/api/observation" />
    </MetadataContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

(the code should run in CRA context, both apis can be replaced with almost any API)

When I run it, a request is fired on both endpoints (/api/capteur and /api/observation), but where I'm expecting the metadata object in the MetadataContextProvider to have 2 keys: "/api/capteur" and "/api/observation", only the content of the last request made appears.

When I console.log metadata in the loadMetadata function, metadata always has the initial state hook value, that is {}.

I'm fairly new to React, I tried hard and I'm really not figuring out what's going on here. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how you update the `metadata` object with `setMetadata`.
The operation of updating the `metadata` object via `loadMetadata` in your context is done by two "instances" respectively: `TestComponent` #1 and `TestComponent` #2.
They both have access to the `metadata` object in your context, but they're not instantly synchronized, as `useState`'s setter function works asynchronously.

The easy solution for your problem is called [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).
`useState`'s setter does also provide a callback function, which will then use (I'm oversimplifying here) the "latest" state.

In your context provider:

```
async function loadMetadata(url) {
  let response = await axios.get(url);
  setMetadata((existingData) => ({ ...existingData, [url]: response.data }));
  // instead of
  // setMetadata({ ...metadata, [url]: response.data });
}
```

Here is a working CodeSandbox:   https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-mclean-syiol?file=/src/App.js

Look at the console to see the order of execution.

---

I highly recommend to [fully read React hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), especially the "Hooks API Reference". There are also other problems with your code (for example missing dependencies in the `useEffect` hook, do you have ESLint enabled?).

If you want to have a better overview on how to use React's context I can recommend Kent C. Dodds' blog:

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Comment: It works like a charm thank you. I already went through hooks documentation, but it looks like I skipped some useful info I'm digging again. I do have ESLint enabled, it points missing dependencies, and is happy when the second arguments to useEffect is [context, url]. But if I do so, I end up in an infinite loop of updates. How am I supposed to do?

Comment: @HugoMerzisen The infinite loop is caused by the context's `loadMetadata` function. Every rerender will recreate the function, which will cause another rerender and so on... This is a topic for itself. You can fix this by using `useMemo` for your context value (this one: `<MetadataContext.Provider value={{ metadata, loadMetadata, postNewItem }}>`), or, in your case, by using `useCallback` for your `loadMetadata` function, which will result in not creating the function every render (Google "useCallback referential equality"):  https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-lake-z1wgk?file=/src/App.js