# Return data from Callback within Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, use-reducer

I have the following problem in a React Context:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
     
    export const Context = React.createContext();
     
    function reducer (state, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'set': {
               SomePackage.parse(action.result, {
                    options: true
                    complete: (result) => {
                        // Result is available here
                    }
                });
            }
            default: {
                throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`)
            }
        }
    }
    
    export function ContextProvider ({ children }) {
        const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, {});
    
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }
```

I can't really find a to return data inside of `reducer` from `SomePackage.parse`. The data that should be set as the new state is only available inside of the `complete`callback and is not returned in any way from `SomePackage.parse`
Is there an elegant way to return those data?

Comment: `SomePackage.parse` doesn't return a new state. Why can't you just return a new object with the updated properties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React useReducer async data fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146795/react-usereducer-async-data-fetch)

Comment: @Andy the data i want to set as the new state are only available inside of the ```complete```callback