# state update waits until promise resolves while using axios in reducer function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
const initialState = {
  data: []
}

function reducer (state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'case':
            return (
                axios.get('/api').then(
                    // res => console.log(res)
                    // res => console.log(res.data)
                    res => ({ data: res.data })
                )
            )
        default:
            return state    
    }
}


export default function Component() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
 
    console.log(state)
    console.log(state.data)

    return (
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'case' })}>button</button>
    )
}
```

In my code, what is my mistake? I get `Promise {<pending>}` and `undefined` after two line of *console.log* inside the Component. It seems state is not being updated before printing `state` on console. How to fix that?

Comment: In that case, I probably do not need to use useReducer anymore. I wanted to leverage this hook as I have 3 cases for 3 different api endpoints. Instead, I will then go back for useState if I had to define functions for onClick handler. Right? @RobinZigmond

Comment: oh sorry, I totally misread - my fault. I had been blinded by "reducer" and thought you were using Redux - but of course you're not, you're using plain React and the `useReducer` hook. In that case my links above are meaningless, although the first part stands - you can't directly do what you're doing, but can make asynchronous requests in the event handler and dispatch based on the result. Sorry again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React useReducer async data fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146795/react-usereducer-async-data-fetch)

Comment: I think the above question covers this area quite well. I note some of the answers also talk about Redux middleware like thunk etc, as I did - but you can't directly use those with useReducer without writing quite a bit of additional "infrastructure" yourself. Basically useReducer is only designed for simple, synchronous, use-cases I think.

Comment: You are not supposed to say sorry man! It's fine. Now, trying the above solutions...

Comment: @RobinZigmond I could not fix the issue yet. The link you provided above doesn't clear everything understandable. Still arise confusions on async operation inside reducer function, as I want to handle api request after dispatch is called and expecting for state update before jsx returns. Better I will get rid off using `useReducer` hook? If this lacks of flexibility ...